# My Android app is not showing in playstore for Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: android, google-play

My Android App is not showing in Playstore for Samsung Galaxy S6. But it is working for all previous Samsung phones or tablets. What is the problem with this Samsung Galaxy S6? Can any one please help me.

Code of Manifest File:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"
        android:maxSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true" 
        android:xlargeScreens="true"

         />


    <compatible-screens>

        <!-- no small size screens -->
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />

        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />


        <!-- all large size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />


        <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />


        <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="213"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="480"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="480"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="480"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />

    </compatible-screens>


    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="false" />
```

Comment: The answer below is ridiculous, the latest SDK is 23, and its only in preview for Nexus devices. I'd look at your attributes for screen size and target density, somewhere in there you are filtering out the S6.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? if so can you publish?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is with  the Galaxy s6 uses a high density

add this sizes

```
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="560" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="640" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="560" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="640" />
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Android official guide doesn't list '640' in the list of acceptable values - see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `android:maxSdkVersion="23"`.

Latest android sdk version is `24.3.4`, and that is what I guess is being shipped in Samsung Galaxy S6.

Comment: You can remove maxSdkVersion. It is not needed

Comment: No, latest SDK version is 23 and its only in preview on select Nexus devices.